# How can the selenium keep in the website not being timed out?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, session, undetected-chromedriver

To try not to session time out, I try this.

```
def IDLE(self, interval_time):
   time.sleep(60 * interval_time)
   self.driver.refresh()
   self.session_id = self.driver.session_id
   self.url = self.driver.current_url
```

But didn't work.

I'd like to keep in the web page for a while not to being timed out.

Answer (score 0):

**Try out the below code, it is made for 5 minutes:**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

class SessionManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.session_id = self.driver.session_id
        self.url = self.driver.current_url

    def keep_session_alive(self, duration_minutes):
        start_time = time.time()
        while time.time() - start_time < duration_minutes * 60:
            self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').click()
            time.sleep(60)

        self.driver.quit()

session_manager = SessionManager()\
session_manager.keep_session_alive(5)
```